# XSLT code to take only first 24 alphanumeric characters

Tags: xslt

I have to build an XSLT code such a way that if input is more than 24 alphanumeric characters.

I have to extract only first 24 alphanumeric characters.

Also, if input is less than 24 characters, the same has to be extracted

Can anyone please provide me the xslt code for this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove non-alphanumeric characters you need to use the "double-translate" trick.  For brevity I'll define a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="allowedChars" select="concat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                                 '0123456789')" />
```

Now to remove all characters from `$theString` that *aren't* in `$allowedChars` you can use

```
translate($theString, translate($theString, $allowedChars, ''), '')
```

The way this works is that the inner `translate`

```
translate($theString, $allowedChars, '')
```

produces a string containing all the characters in `$theString` that are *not allowed*, and the outer translate then removes all *those* from the original string, leaving only the valid characters.

You can then truncate the result to 24 characters using the [`substring` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you might have non-alphanumeric characters in your input, use translate to remove them, using the method described in Ian Roberts' answer

and then cut the input at your max length with substring like so

```
substring($translated_input, 1, 24)
```

Comment: But if the input is less than 24 characters in length. Will the substring function not throw error?

Comment: It won't throw an error, "The returned substring contains those characters for which the position of the character is greater than or equal to the rounded value of the second argument and, if the third argument is specified, less than the sum of the rounded value of the second argument and the rounded value of the third argument" from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: That `translate` will do nothing, you need the "double-translate" trick in order to remove the offending characters.

Comment: Thanks, removed my broken advice.